# retrieving data from json with python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have a nested JSON data. I want to get the value of key "name" inside the dictionary "value" based on the key "id" in "key" dictionary (let the user enter the id). I don't want to use indexing which, because places are changing on every url differently. Also data is large, so I need one row solution (without for loop).

**Code**

```
import requests, re, json

r = requests.get('https://www.trendyol.com/apple/macbook-air-13-m1-8gb-256gb-ssd-altin-p-67940132').text

json_data1 = json.loads(re.search(r"window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__=({.*}});window", r).group(1))

print(json_data1)

print('json_data1:',json_data1['product']['attributes'][0]['value']['name'])
```

**Output**

```
{'product': {'attributes': [{'key': {'name': 'İşlemci Tipi', 'id': 168}, 'value': {'name': 'Apple M1', 'id': 243383}, 'starred': True, 'description': '', 'mediaUrls': []}, {'key': {'name': 'SSD Kapasitesi', 'id': 249}..........
json_data1: Apple M1
```

**JSON Data**

```
{
"product": {
  "attributes": [
    {
      "key": { "name": "İşlemci Tipi", "id": 168 },
      "value": { "name": "Apple M1", "id": 243383 },
      "starred": true,
      "description": "",
      "mediaUrls": []
    },
    {
      "key": { "name": "SSD Kapasitesi", "id": 249 },
      "value": { "name": "256 GB", "id": 3376 },
      "starred": true,
      "description": "",
      "mediaUrls": []
    },
    .
    .
    .
    ]
}
}
```

**Expected Output is getting value by key id: (type must be str)**

> input >> id: 168
>
> output >> name: Apple M1

Comment: You want to print only the id (which is 168) or do u want to print it along with the "name"? what is ur expected output?

Comment: so you're trying to fetch the name of the item based on a certain id?

Comment: yes. I will give the id from "key" and according to that will take the name "value". please check again the question. explained in the last rows detailed.

Comment: "I don't want to use indexing which, because places are changing on every url differently." What *do* you want to use? What is the *rule that tells you* where the "changed place" is? "Also data is large, so I need one row solution (without for loop)." If any element in the `'attributes': ` could be the one you want (i.e. there are no rules, such as sortedness, that let you rule some of them out automatically), and you can't know until you look at the element, then **there is no way to avoid looking at all of them** to figure out which one matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you originally didn't want a for loop, but now it's a matter of speed,

Here's a solution with for loop, you can test it and see if it's faster than the one you already had

```
import json

with open("file.json") as f:
 data = json.load(f)

search_key = int(input("Enter id: "))

for i in range(0, len(data['product']['attributes'])):
 if search_key == data['product']['attributes'][i]['key']['id']:
  print(data['product']['attributes'][i]['value']['name'])
```

> Input >> Enter id: 168

> Output >> Apple M1

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with for loop. It works fast so I preferred it.

```
for i in json_data1['product']['attributes']:
    cpu = list(list(i.values())[0].values())[1]
    if cpu == 168:
        print(list(list(i.values())[1].values())[0])
```

Comment: So you originally didn't try any "for loop" in first place, nor did you know how fast it is?

Comment: I tried with the runcoderun's solution. My solution is better with 20ms.

Comment: @piseynir I have added a comparison to my answer to show that an iterator is in fact faster.

Answer (score 0):

Iteration is unavoidable if the index is unknown, but the cost can be reduced substantially by using a [generator expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/) and Python's built-in [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function:

```
next((x["value"]["name"] for x in data["product"]["attributes"] if x["key"]["id"] == 168), None)
```

To verify that a generator expression is in fact faster than a for loop, here is a comparison of the running time of xFranko's solution and the above:

```
import time

def time_func(func):
        
    def timer(*args):
        
        time1 = time.perf_counter()
        func(*args)
        time2 = time.perf_counter()
        
        return (time2 - time1) * 1000
    
    return timer

number_of_attributes = 100000

data = {
    "product": {
        "attributes": [
            {
                "key": { "name": "İşlemci Tipi", "id": i },
                "value": { "name": "name" + str(i), "id": 243383 },
                "starred": True,
                "description": "",
                "mediaUrls": []
            } for i in range(number_of_attributes)
        ]
    }
}

def getName_generator(id):
    return next((x["value"]["name"] for x in data["product"]["attributes"] if x["key"]["id"] == id), None)

def getName_for_loop(id):
    return_value = None
    
    for i in range(0, len(data['product']['attributes'])):
        if id == data['product']['attributes'][i]['key']['id']:
            return_value = data['product']['attributes'][i]['value']['name']
    
    return return_value

print("Generator:", time_func(getName_generator)(0))
print("For loop:", time_func(getName_for_loop)(0))

print()

print("Generator:", time_func(getName_generator)(number_of_attributes - 1))
print("For loop:", time_func(getName_for_loop)(number_of_attributes - 1))
```

**My results:**

```
Generator: 0.0075999999999964984
For loop: 43.73920000000003

Generator: 23.633300000000023
For loop: 49.839699999999986
```

**Conclusion:**

For large data sets, a generator expression is indeed faster, even if it has to traverse the entire set.